# Extracting price from string

Tags: ios, regex, ios7, nsscanner

I am looking for a short and convenient way to extract a product's price from NSString.
I have tried regular expressions, but always found some cases where did not match.

The price can be any number including decimals, 0 **and -1** (valid prices: 10, 10.99, -1, 0).
NSString can contain a string like: @"Prod. price: $10.99"

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot cover 100% cases, don't even try to achieve that.

Comment: So what do you suggest to do?

Comment: "Prod. price: $10.99" is this your default string format?

Comment: No, it is just an example.. it can be "$10.99" or "10.99"

Comment: It depends on ow well defined the surrounding context is. For example, is there always a preceding  "$"? Is the price always at the end of the string? Provide full examples and the REs you have tried? Also have you tried `NSScanner`?

Comment: No, but the numbers are always together. Maybe scan to the first number and then continue until I see a number and/or . ?

Comment: I have tried (\\+|-)?([0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)) and /^0$|^-?[1-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$/. both of them found on SO and they did not match all the cases above

Comment: (\\+|-)?([0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)) does not match 0 nor -1. Why?

Comment: If you don't understand REs don't use them. Instead use `NSScanner`. `NSScanner` can be painful but it is straight forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will match all the examples you have given

```
-?\d+(\.\d{2})?
```

Optionally a `-`, followed by 1-many digits, optionally followed by a decimal point and 2 more digits.

If you've got other numbers that are not prices mixed in to the data then I don't think regex can fulfil your needs.

Comment: If I want not only 2 numbers after decimal, then change it to: -?(\d+)(\.\d+)? ?

Comment: Why two capture groups? `(-?\d+\.\d+)?`

Comment: @Zaph, you're right that the first group doesn't need to be captured (we're taking the whole match not any of the capture groups anyway) - will change that now. The 2nd group is in brackets because the `?` applies to only the `\.\d{2}`. - I could make it a non-capturing group, but like I said, we're ignoring the groups anyway.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *originalString = @"Prod. price: $10.99";

NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:originalString];
NSCharacterSet *numbers = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"-0123456789"];

[scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:numbers intoString:NULL];
double number;
[scanner scanDouble:&number];
```

number is equal to `10.99`

Obviously if you have other numbers before the value you looking for you wont find it.

Comment: Works, but a simpler solution is OGHaza's answer, using regex.. ))

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your NSString will always contain the price with $ prep-ended to it, the following regex will match your need

.*?\$(-?(\d+)(.\d{1,2})?)

Once the above regex is matched you can find out match.group(1) to be the price from the NSString.

Comment: No, $ is not obligatory