# Parse price from a string with decimals and currency

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have various kinds of inputs like `$1.30` , `$0.30` , `1.3Rs.`, `13EUR`

How can i get the only integer value like `$1.30 = 1` , `$0.30=0` , `100.3Rs. = 100`, `13EUR = 13`

Comment: I used [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20047566/extracting-price-from-string) and [That](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221629/how-to-get-number-from-a-string). But both are different than me. And I dont't even know if it is possible by REGEX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regex to extract the data as you dont seem to care about the decimals

```
Regex.Match(yourString, "\\d+")
```

And then you can cast the results you get from the match